# jQuery reinitiate css :after on div after jquery function terminated

Tags: jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

I am creating a justified gallery using the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/3/

I also use infinitescroll to load more items.

Current js:

```
$("#posts").infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
loading: {
    finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
    img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
  }
},

function( newElements ) {
            $( newElements ).each(function() {
                $(this).css("width", $(this).width());
            }); 
            $('#posts').removeClass('posts').addClass('posts');
}
);
```

CSS:

```
#posts.posts{
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#posts.posts .post{
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}

#posts.posts:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

This code works for the fist chunk of loaded items, but ignores the items loaded with infinite scroll

Already tried this (found as an answer in another similar post):

```
$("head").append($('<style>div#posts:after { content: "";width:100%;display:inline-block;font-size:0;line-height:0; }</style>'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
Each new element should have a space added
Just added it with `$(this).before("&nbsp;");`

New is is:

```
$("#posts").infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
loading: {
    finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
    img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
  }
},

function( newElements ) {
            $( newElements ).each(function() {
                $(this).before("&nbsp;");
                $(this).css("width", $(this).width());
            }); 
            $('#posts').removeClass('posts').addClass('posts');
}
);
```